# Access deactivated app development account of facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Formal procedure to initiate `FB.init()`

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.0'
    });
  };
```

There may be the situation a developer in one organization moves to another and he wants to deactivate his previous organization facebook page and developer account. Next, If there is any connected module of that deactivated account, How to validate that hypothetical scenario and steps need for consequence procedures?

What happens with appId of a deactivated facebook account?

Comment: why would you provide an app id that is wrong or not valid?

Comment: In future, I may delete that application in facebook developers account. But I try to initialize `FB.init()` with the same appId, which is not existing until I encounter an error in `FB.login()` or `FB.getLoginStatus()`. Just an avid to validate appId before encountering an error.